# Why does contravariance only allow the reverse of assign compatible?

Tags: c#, contravariance

The `IComparable<in T>` interface is defined as **Contra-Variance**.

**Contra-Variance** wrote the following code to check what constraint there is.

```cs
public class Parent : IComparable<Parent>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Parent other) => 
        string.Compare(Name, other.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}

public class Child : Parent
{
}
```

```cs
public static void Compare(IComparable<Child> comparable, Child target)
{
    var result = comparable.CompareTo(target);
}
```

```cs
IComparable<Parent> parentComparable = new Parent {Name = "Parent"};
var child = new Child {Name = "Child"};
        
Compare(parentComparable, child);
```

Code that receives `IComparable<Parent>` as an `IComparable<Child>`. It shows typical **Contra-Variance** characteristics.

But suddenly, this thought occurred to me.

Can't I pass an `IComparable<Child>` as an `IComparable<Parent>`? Of course, It's not possible because `IComparable<in T>` is **Contra-Variance**. But, if possible, I wondered, is there a logical problem?

There seems to be no problem in my opinion.

So why doesn't C# Compiler allow it? Maybe am I wrong?

Comment: You can't pass `IComparable<Child>` to a parameter typed to `IComparable<Parent>` because `IComparable<Child>` does not inherit from `IComparable<Parent>`.

Comment: Just because two types exhibit a particular inheritance relationship (say `C` is a child of `P`), that *doesn't* mean that a single generic type parameterized by those types assumes the same inheritance relationship (`G<C>` isn't a child of `G<P>`)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Of course, as you said, it's impossible. The question assumes the above situation.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever **Co-Variance** is not an inheritance relationship, right? Similarly, wouldn't **Contra-Variance** be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical problem is very obvious if you try to construct an example like this:

```
public class Parent {
    
}

public class Child: Parent, IComparable<Child> {
    public int SomethingSpecificToChild { get; }
    
    public int CompareTo(Child other) => SomethingSpecificToChild.CompareTo(other.SomethingSpecificToChild);
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        ExpectsComparableParent(new Child());
    }
    
    public static void ExpectsComparableParent(IComparable<Parent> parent) {
        parent.CompareTo(new Parent());
    }
}
```

Here I am passing `new Child()` as the parameter of `ExpectsComparableParent`, which expects a `IComparable<Parent>`. If this did compile, then at runtime the `parent.CompareTo` call would resolve to the `CompareTo` declared in `Child`, and the line

```
SomethingSpecificToChild.CompareTo(other.SomethingSpecificToChild);
```

would run. However, the parameter `other` is passed an argument of `new Parent()`, which doesn't actually have a `SomethingSpecificToChild` property.

Another way to see this is to list what `IComparable<Parent>` and `IComparable<Child>` can do.

`IComparable<Parent>` can be compared with any instance of `Parent` or any instance of `Child`, since you can pass an instance of `Child` into `IComparable<Parent>.CompareTo`.

`IComparable<Child>` can only be compared with any instance of `Child`.

Clearly, `IComparable<Parent>` can do everything that `IComparable<Child>` can do, *and more*, hence an instance of `IComparable<Parent>` can be converted to `IComparable<Child>`, but not vice versa.

It’s also worth noting that contravariant types’ subtyping relationship being the opposite of the subtyping relationship of the their type parameters is exactly what the “contra-“ in “contravariance” is referring to :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what I'm doing wrong :)